# Generates first degree exponential equations

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, algebra

I try to generate a list of first degree exponential equations in the real ones and that the solution is in logarithm in base 10 as simplified as possible, for example x= log(7) , where log is in base 10, but I have some problems
1)It seems that some solutions remain negative, I can't or don't know how to catch the error so that it generates another one
2)I need to catch the case that an identity occurs ,y do not get a zero elevated to x
3) I need the solution not to comment on complexes or errors.

Please help me

this is the code I have so far

```
SetSystemOptions[
"SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False];
tope = 10;
num = 7;
k := Random[Integer, {1, tope}]
k1 := Random[Integer, {1, tope}]
dat = Table[eq = k*(k1 + 3)^(x + k1) == (k1 + k)*Abs[(k - k1)]^x
Flatten[{eq // TraditionalForm, 
Simplify[x /. Solve[eq, x], Reals]}], {num}];
Print[StyleForm[
TableForm[dat, 
TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"Ecuación ", " Sol "}}], 
FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> "Bold"]]
```

**Update
this is what I am trying to do, the exponential equations must be of first degree, whose solution is only found by means of logarithms in base 10**

[image: this is the idea]

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain your general aim. Are these equations assumed as a task for students? If so, should they solve them by hand, of within Mma? Further, it is not clear what do you want to achieve with the `Flatten`operation? It seems to be multiplied by the right-hand part of your equation in the code. Is it intensionally?

Comment: What do you want to print: equations? Solutions? Both?

Comment: It seems that the form of the equation is such that most often the solution for x is negative. Seems that you do not like it. What is wrong with the negative solution?

Comment: hello, thank you for answering 
If I am helping my sister who has to give her high school students (45), set of 30 different exercises for each one and send them in pdf to their 
 The school will send an email with the answer for them to make and then give feedback to those who can't move forward. By passing it to them in response, it only cares about those students who have doubts and doesn't have to spend time solving them all.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch-When I execute my code, MMA tells me some errors that I can not catch and therefore does not generate the exercises, maybe I express myself wrong, it does not matter if the results are positive or negative, misinterpret the error that sends MMA. The expression that generates the equations is random, it does not have to be that one, it matters that sometimes x appears on the right or left or both

Comment: As for the expression "Flatten" someone once helped me to put an equation and use that instruction, the truth is not how it influences the result, ah the results should be in base 10 because the natural logarithms are not studied,the important thing is that it generates the exercises in the real ones without any error or commentary in the answer

Comment: Please give an actual example of an equation you want to generate. It is not clear from your code what you want to do. By the way, `Table[expr,{num}]` will generate a list of duplicate expressions since you don't supply an index variable and use it in the expression.

Comment: @Somos see update above

Comment: See my edits to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

I think we should take care that there are no equations containing the term  `0^x` and let us also remove equations that exhibit no (real) solution. Therefore, let us initially create more equations and their solutions than we finally need with the number numMax (say, numMax=50) and then only leave first num (say, num=5) of those that are left.

This creates a list of random integer pairs {k,k1}:

```
Clear[k, k1, tope, num, x];
tope = 10;
num = 5;
numMax = 50;

  q =Take[Select[
   RandomInteger[{1, tope}, {numMax,2}], 
#[[1]] - #[[2]] > 0 && #[[2]] > -3 &], num]

(* {{7, 6}, {4, 2}, {10, 6}, {3, 1}, {5, 4}, {10, 3}, {5, 4}} *)
```

We here already took care that the term `0^x` will not appear in the equations.

This defines your equation:

```
 eqA[{k_, k1_}] := k*(k1 + 3)^(x + k1) == (k1 + k)*Abs[(k - k1)]^x;
```

Now let us make a list `lst1` which we will later transform and then draw as a table. We will simultaneously take care to remove from this list those equations that have no solution:

```
lst1 = 
      Take[Map[{eqA[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}], 
           Solve[eqA[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}], x, Reals] /. {{a_ -> b_}} -> b} &,
          q] /. {a_, {}} -> Nothing, num]



(*  {{8 5^(2 + x) == 5 2^(1 + x) 3^x, (2 Log[2] + Log[5])/(
      Log[2] + Log[3] - Log[5])}, {10 7^(4 + x) == 7 2^(1 + x) 3^x, (
      Log[5] + 3 Log[7])/(
      Log[2] + Log[3] - Log[7])}, {7 8^(5 + x) == 
       3 2^(2 + x), (-13 Log[2] + Log[3] - Log[7])/(
      2 Log[2])}, {6 5^(2 + x) == 2^(3 + 2 x), (-2 Log[2] + Log[3] + 
       2 Log[5])/(
      2 Log[2] - Log[5])}, {2 5^(3 + x) == 3 2^(2 + 3 x), (-Log[2] - 
       Log[3] + 3 Log[5])/(3 Log[2] - Log[5])}}   *)
```

Now let us add the numeration and column headings

```
 lst = Join[{{"", Style["Equacion", 18, Black, Bold], 
    Style["Solucion", 18, Black, Bold]}}, 
  MapThread[Insert[#1, #2, 1] &, {lst1, Range[num]}]];
```

Now we can draw the table:

```
Grid[lst, Frame -> True,
   Dividers -> All, ItemStyle -> FontSize -> 16,
   Background -> {None, 
   None, {{1, 1} -> Pink, {{1, 1}, {2, -1}} -> GrayLevel[.9],
         {{2, -1}, {1, 1}} -> GrayLevel[.9]
    } } ]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

You can now collect the whole code into one cell, evaluate it, and then collapse the cell around the output to hide the code. After this, you can either print the notebook or save it as the pdf to distribute it among the users.

Have fun!

Comment: ,see update above

Comment: _for some strange reason, I get errors of various kinds, you could publish the complete and compact code complete, maybe something I do more, I've done nas of 5 times and went crazy MMA

Comment: @zeros It perfectly works for me (Win 10, Mma 12.1.1.0). Check that you did not miss anything from the code and that numMax>num.

Answer (score 1):

You mostly had the right pieces, but you needed some more code. Try this following code. You
will have to customize it a bit if you need to,
but it seems to be close to what you want. Note
that sometimes there will be errors in finding
solutions, but it will be easier to just find
another batch of solutions.

```
ClearAll[logi, logr, x, doit];
logi[n_] := Plus @@ (#[[2]]*Log[#[[1]]]&) /@
   FactorInteger[n];
logr[r_] := logi@Numerator@r - logi@Denominator@r;
doit[tope_, num_] := Module[{k, k1, equ, sol},
   Table[
      k = Random[ Integer, {1, tope}];
     k1 = Random[ Integer, {1, tope}];
     If[k == k1, k1++]; (* to avoid 0^x *)
     equ = k*(k1+3)^(x+k1) == (k1+k)*Abs[k-k1]^x;
     sol = Simplify[ First@First[ x /. Solve[ 
       equ, x, Rationals]]];
     TradtionalForm /@ {equ, x ==
        sol /. Log[r_] :> logr@r},
   {num}]];
dat = doit[10, 3];
Print@ Style[ TableForm[ dat,       
   TableHeadings -> {Automatic, {"Ecuación ", " Solución "}}], 
   FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 18,
   FontWeight -> Bold];
```

Comment: @Somos_It works quite well , there was a syntax error in TradtionalForm , but I corrected it , it is possible that the output will come out using "Grid" o "GridBox"

Comment: @Somos_Thanks for your time, can you think of an algebraic expression that does not generate negative results, even though I look for one, the results are always negative.